# Crystal Reports : Crosstab refuses not to paginate

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I am using Crystal Reports 11 (XI) and I have a crosstab that has quite a few rows to it. Its publishing format is to Excel, so pagination doesn't really even make sense. However, no matter what I do it repeats the column/crosstab headers every couple dozen lines. I've tried:

-Increasing page size definition to max size (12x18) portrait

-Turning off pagination in the output settings

-Turning off horizontal pagination

-Deleting column headers (works) but I cannot delete the crosstab header

I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Are you using BOE or reporting straight out of Crystal?

Comment: Not using BOE. Using a third party piece of software that has a Crystal interface. I feed it a crystal template and a proprietary 'table' object and it generates the report.

Comment: What is this third-party tool? Have you tested the report with Crystal's Report Viewer instead?

Comment: You want to repeat header on each page ??????

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is just to create an excel file with some pivoted data crystal reports is not the best way to do it. Check the first 5 minutes of this video:
http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/Preview_Demo.aspx
It compares the same data presented as a cross-tab in Crystal reports and pivot report based on a SQL ad-hoc query. SSRS is also part of the comparison and it is a better choice than Crystal too , but SQL ad-hoc query is my favorite for pivoted data.

P.S. I am proposing this alternative because the tool is free, it will save you development time and will create a better formatted excel file.  If you are using BOE and you want to keep the report there this might not work for you.

Comment: As I mention above I am not using BOE but other third party software that interfaces with crystal templates. Believe me if I could use another reporting stack I would because I absolutely loathe Crystal. But the third party application only accepts Crystal templates.

Comment: Then try the tool above , you can request a free license from this link: [link](http://www.r-tag.com/Pages/FreeCrystalReportsViewer.aspx)
What is the name of the tool, which is in use now?

Comment: So here's the wonderful combination of factors leading me to this situation.

First off I am using a financial application (vendor named OpenLink) that is highly specialized for a particular business purpose. They sell an in-application reporting solution which attempts to mimic some of the basic features of BOE in terms of report designing and security. Otherwise they are dissimilar, It can only run adhoc reports. The supported export method is w/ crystal template. The users want a one-click Excel report and the ONLY way to do that is with a Crystal->Excel template

Comment: I am not very clear what is the problem. You cannot use another tool or the data is not accessible except through OpenLink? If you are having troubles to access the data contact the companies ( either OpenLink or R-Tag) and check what are the options. Crystal reports creates a temp copy of the report in the temp folder. You can check what this report is doing and create another report , which will retrieve the same data but in a better format. Depending of the database type you might check also what is the command sent by OpenLink and use it directly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as contrived as the problem...

There is no way in Crystal XI to "turn off" the crosstab pagination. It simply cannot be stopped. However, you can cheat the system by configuring a massive page size. In windows on your development machine, locate your XPS printer virtual device and choose "Print Server Properties" (in the top banner in Win 7+)

In the "Forms" tab, you will be able to configure a new paper form object of arbitrary size. Click on "Change Form Settings" and create a new page that is as large as you think you will need. I'm not aware of any limitations on this configuration, but I'm sure bad things happen if you go nuts.

Returning to crystal, go to printer configuration and select the XPS document printer as your target device for exports, and save the custom page size as the target paper type.

Now, the crosstab will assume you are printing to a massive sheet and will not attempt to paginate. As far as I can tell it's impossible to achieve the same effect any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a introduction about jasper crosstab.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jasper_reports/pdf/jasper_crosstabs.pdf

From the document, you can add two attributes in  node

`<crosstab isRepeatColumnHeaders="false" isRepeatRowHeaders="false">
    ...
</crosstab>`